# Where does Bash's "not found" message come from?

Tags: linux, bash

If I type an invalid command in Bash, I get:

```
$ asdf
asdf: not found
```

I've been led to believe the "not found" message comes from a fallback executable that Bash calls when it can't find the command you enter. What is the name and path of this executable?

Comment: Not `/bin/bash`?

Comment: No, it's bash that says so. (Mine even says so itself: `bash: asdf: command not found`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to Rena's answer, yes it is a function -- *and you can replace it!*

[This link details how to do it](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-command-not-found). Fascinating post, actually. Just in time for April Fool's! [sl](http://www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~toyoda/index_e.html) command anyone?

Generously lifted from the linked article (for posterity) is this code snippet on placing this function in your `.bashrc` on an openSUSE platform:

```
command_not_found_handle() {

    export TEXTDOMAIN=command-not-found

    local cmd state rest
    local -i pid ppid pgrp session tty_nr tpgid

    # do not run when inside Midnight Commander or within a Pipe
    if test -n "$MC_SID" -o ! -t 1 ; then
        echo $"$1: command not found"
        return 127
    fi

    # do not run when within a subshell
    read pid cmd state ppid pgrp session tty_nr tpgid rest  < /proc/self/stat
    if test $$ -eq $tpgid ; then
        echo "$1: command not found"
        return 127
    fi

    # test for /usr/sbin and /sbin
    if test -x "/usr/sbin/$1" -o -x "/sbin/$1" ; then
        if test -x "/usr/sbin/$1" ; then prefix='/usr' ; else prefix='' ; fi
        echo $"Absolute path to '$1' is '$prefix/sbin/$1', so running it may require superuser privileges (eg. root)."
        return 127
    fi

    if test -n "$COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_AUTO" ; then
        # call command-not-found directly
        test -x /usr/bin/python && test -x /usr/bin/command-not-found && /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/command-not-found "$1" zypp
    else
        # print only info about command-not-found
        echo -e $"If '$1' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:\n    cnf $1"
    fi

    return 127
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is issued by `bash` itself.  Try

```
strings `which bash` | fgrep found
```

Answer (score 1):

Did some further digging and found out it's not an executable, but a function, command_not_found_handle() within Bash.